# After executing docker-compose command geting error yaml.scanner.ScannerError

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Docker compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
        -8080:80
    environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:vvk123
mysql:
    image:mysql:latest
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:vvk123
```

when i was tring to execute this command

```
docker-compose ps
```

its giving error called

> yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here in
>   ".\docker-compose.yml", line 12, column 20

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a space after the column in line 12:

```
version: '2'

services:

wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    environment:
        - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD:vvk123
mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:vvk123
```

Comment: And also I think, there should be a space between `-` and `8080` as well

Comment: Edited the answer, I miss it due the error was pointing to line 12, maybe it does work...